# Why is $L=\{\langle M \rangle \mid |L(M)| \geq k\}$ not recognizable?

Tags: computability, semi-decidability

Here $M$ denotes a turing machine.

By set theory, $L = \overline{E_{TM}} \cap \overline{L_0} \cap \overline{L_1}$ where $L_i=\{\langle M \rangle \mid |L(M)|=i\}$. And I know that $\overline{E_{TM}}$ is recognizable.

That is about all I know at this point. I suppose I need to use mapping reducibility to prove $L$ is not recognizable, but am not sure how.

Comment: The $L$ in the title looks as r.e. (recognizable) to me. A semidecider can be defined using some dovetailing, as far as I can see. By the way, what is $E_{TM}$? Empty-language TMs? Why your alternative definition in the text for $L$ does not use $k$?

Comment: Yes $E_{TM}$ denotes the set of turing machines $M$ with $L(M)$ empty. And yes I forgot to include $L_2$, $L_3$,...,$L_{k-1}$ in my expression, but you get the idea.

Comment: Now I see what you mean, thanks. Note that we have $E_{TM} = L_0$, so there's some redundancy in your expression. Still, I still think $L$ _is_ recognizable.

Comment: Your language is indeed recognizable. What is the actual question you are trying to solve?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? Because I've seen a similar example $L_k = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid |L(M)| = k \}$ which is neither recognizable nor co-recognizable.

Comment: The language $\{ \langle M \rangle \mid |L(M)| \geq k \}$ is r.e. but not co-r.e. The language $\{ \langle M \rangle \mid |L(M)| \leq k \}$ is co-r.e. but not r.e. Finally, the language $\{ \langle M \rangle \mid |L(M)| = k \}$ is neither r.e. nor co-r.e. All of these might look similar, but they belong to different classes.

Comment: Ok, so clearly I can't use set theory and closure properties of recognizable languages to show $L$ is recognizable. What should I do instead?